# Cannot access functions in autoloaded library

Tags: php, composer-php

Im autoloading a library via composer. But when i try to call on functions in it nothing happens. I dont get any errors that point me in any direction, nothing just happens.

The library in this case is:
https://github.com/RinkAttendant6/JsonI18n

But it seems like the same thing happens regardless of what external library im trying. Is it something with composer that i have forgot to config? Anything with my php installation? (php 7.1).

The code im using for this specific library looks like this.

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
$t = new \JsonI18n\Translate('en-CA');
$t->addResource('lang.json'); //it breaks here

//when i var_dump $t i get NULL.
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `require_once()`. Open a terminal and `cd` to do your root folder of your project. Then type `composer require rinkattendant6/json-i18n` in the console.

To use it:

```
use \JsonI18n\Translate;

$t = new \JsonI18n\Translate('en-CA');
$t->addResource('lang.json'); //i
```